# How to create multiple child object from Lead object

Tags: trigger

I want the ability to create multiple VOBs on a single patient lead and have all of them follow the same automated process flow which I have created. I know we could manually create duplicate fields for a second VOB on a Lead record and run it through the process that way, but there must be a way to just have multiple VOBs in the Lead – VOB relationship.

I tried with the below code but get the error as "Line: 12, Column: -1
line breaks not allowed in string literals "

```
 trigger CreateVOB on Lead__c (after insert) {
 list<VOB__c> VOBList = new list<VOB__c>();
     for(Lead l : trigger.new)
     {
        VOB__c VOB = new VOB__c ();
        VOB.Lead = l.id;
        VOB.Name = 'testName'; 
        VOBList.add(VOB);
        if (l.VOB__c){
           for(Lead act: actList)
           {
              VOB = new VOB__c(Lead=Lead.Id,Name='testName);
              VOB.Lead__c = l.Id;
              VOBList.add(VOB);
           }
        }     
     }
     insert VOBList;
```

[image]

Comment: Process Builder...

Comment: There is something about your business use case that isn't clear. When a `Lead__c` is inserted, how many VOB children are you trying to create? And if more than one, how do you know how many and how to populate?

Comment: I want to create 4 VOB children when lead is created

Comment: with what values for VOB 1, vs VOB 2, vs VOB 3 vs VOB 4?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `'`.

```apex
for(Lead act: actList)
       {
          VOB = new VOB__c(Lead=Lead.Id,Name='testName);//You have not closed your string literal
          VOB.Lead__c = l.Id;
          VOBList.add(VOB);
       }
```

Should be:

```apex
for(Lead act: actList)
       {
          VOB = new VOB__c(Lead=Lead.Id,Name='testName');
          VOB.Lead__c = l.Id;
          VOBList.add(VOB);
       }
```

Comment: I tried with the above code but still get the error below : Line: 1, Column: 0
required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'trigger

Comment: @kunalgupta Have you actually saved the trigger or are you trying to execute that through Anonymous Apex in the Developer Console?

Comment: Hi @Jesse I am trying to execute through Anonymous Apex in the developer console.

Comment: @kunalgupta You need to save your trigger.

Comment: When I try to save the trigger ,I get the error which is attached i the screenshot above.

Comment: @kunalgupta - `Lead` can't be a field on `VOB__c` (as that would be a standard field) - are you sure it isn't `lead__c` ?  I think Jesse just copied what you had to solve problem #1, leading to exposing your coding error.

Comment: Hi @cropredy :Could you suggest me a code so that my requirement is fulfilled. I want the ability to create multiple VOBs on a single patient lead and have all of them follow the same automated process flow which I have created. I know we could manually create duplicate fields for a second VOB on a Lead record and run it through the process that way, but there must be a way to just have multiple VOBs in the Lead – VOB relationship.